# How can i make a field based on other choices of other field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have models contain all assets (printer , computer, scanner, photo copier, ...  ) and I saved it at one table as below:

```
class Assets(models.Model):
Tag = models.CharField (max_length = 20, unique=True)
SN = models.CharField (max_length = 20, unique=True)
IP = models.IPAddressField (null=True, blank=True)
MacAddress = models.CharField (max_length = 25, null=True, blank=True)
AssetsType = (
    ('Printer','Printer'),
    ('Monitor','Monitor'),
    ('Scanner','Scanner'),
    ('Personal Computer','PC'),
    ('Laptop','Laptop'),
    ('IPAD', 'IPad'),
    ('IMAC', 'IMac'),
    ('PhotoCopier','PhotoCopier'),
    )
Type = models.CharField (max_length = 25 , choices= AssetsType)
employee = models.ForeignKey (Employee, null=True, blank=True)
building = models.ForeignKey (Location, to_field ='Building', related_name = 'Buliding_Name')
```

Question is, I want to ask about which type of printer if the user choose printer, and as for scanner, I want to ask for type of scanner used ?

I want the type field of scanner or printer appear only if the user choose either printer or scanner?

Comment: If you want to do that dynamically you need to use AJAX.

Comment: thanks alot @zx8754 but is there anyway to do it in the admin page?